# Taking the limit and differentiating with two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

Suppose we have the function $y(x,\epsilon)$.

Does $\frac{d}{dx}\big[\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow{0}}y(x,\epsilon)\big]$ equal $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow{0}}\big[\frac{d}{dx}y(x,\epsilon)\big]$ always?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately not. For example, you could have a function which tends to the zero function as $\epsilon \to 0$, such as
\begin{equation}
f(x,\epsilon) = \epsilon \sin \frac{x}{\epsilon}.
\end{equation}
Here we have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(x,\epsilon) = 0$, so $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} \left[ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(x,\epsilon) \right] = 0$ as well. However,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} f(x,\epsilon) = \cos \frac{x}{\epsilon}. \tag{*}
\end{equation}
The limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ of $(*)$ does not exist, and is definitely unequal to $0$: take for example $x = 0$, then $\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d} x} (0,\epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon$.